# Creating partition on u-boot for flashing

Tags: linux, partition, u-boot

As a beginner in kernel, working on embedded project, that requires me to flash the kernel image into emmc partition in u-boot.But when i tried to mount the SD card into one partition of the u-boot, there are no such partition as in complete boot of kernel(command df -h).

Please guide, how to create the partition in u-boot and mount the SD-card in one of the file system of u-boot if it is possible to create the partition in u-boot.

Note:I know u-boot is Universal boot loader which has limited libraries and utilities.

Comment: *"partition of/on/in u-boot"* -- Your phrasing makes no sense.  U-Boot does not consist of or own any partitions.  What *"image"* (bootloader, U-Boot, kernel, rootfs) are you trying to write to *"emmc"* or SDcard?  What SoC or board are you using (i.e. each SoC has its own boot requirements or conventions)?

Comment: @sawdust, Is it meaningful now?.

Comment: *"create the partition in u-boot"* -- If this is supposed to mean "*use* U-Boot to create some kind of partition on a SDcard", then the answer is "no".  U-Boot does not have any capability to create MBR-type partitions.